# Change div color when button is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying change background/add new button when 'add to basket' is not visible (shoper default option when run of stock)

Here is my attempt with jquery:
`$(".product"){ if ($(.addtobasket).css("display") == "none") { (".buttons",this  ).css("background-color:red!important");`

});

Also i have tried this:

```
         if($(".addtobasket",  ).is(":hidden")){ 
              
              $(".buttons",this )("background-color:red!important");
                                      }
```

});

Of course color is just to check if its working. Any idea what could be wrong??

Comment: can you show html as well?

Comment: Yes, sure it's this site: https://cgmcoffeeshop.pl/pl/c/SUSZ-CBD/19 It's saas shop

Comment: can you add only relevant html in your asked question ?

Answer (score 0):

You may check this one.
JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/gvkat64h/2/

I think a better approach would be to get element By Id.
and also instead of checking if it is hidden we are using hasClass method.

```
 if(  $("#addtobasket"  ).hasClass("hidden")  ){ 
              
            $(".buttons" ).addClass( "red" );
 
}
```

and also I added id to your button copying from the link you provided.

```
<button type="submit" id="addtobasket" class="addtobasket hidden btn btn-red">
```

Comment: Thanks, buyt Your solution works for all boxes or none, because button turns hidden when item count goes to 0.. via backend. I only got access to template files.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs it here is working code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.product').each(function (index, elem) {
 const addToBasketExists = $('.addtobasket', elem).length !== 0;
 if (!addToBasketExists) {
    // Tu zmieniaj co chcesz. W 2gim parametrze przekazuje elem, wtedy jQuery bedzie szukac tylko elementow wewnatrz tej konkretnej DIV z klasa product
    $('.buttons', elem).css('background', 'white')
 }
});
```